# Django: How to assign foreign key in URL to a Createview form

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a review system to items on the site.
in order to do that I created 2 models one for the item (Festival) and one for the reviews. the item is a foreign key of the review.
What I'm trying to do is passing the PK of the item in the url and set it as a foreign key of the review.
I'm currently getting this error: 
NoReverseMatch at /festivals/55/
Reverse for 'create_review' with arguments '(55,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['festivals/create/review/$']

I spent ages trying to solve this :/

Views.py:

```
class CreateReview(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
form_class = forms.ReviewFormCreate
model = models.Review
template_name = 'festival_list/review_form.html'
success_url = '/'

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    form.instance.festival = get_object_or_404(models.Festival, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return super(CreateReview, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls.py
    `path('create/review/<int:pk>',views.CreateReview.as_view(),name='create_review'),`

Models

class Review(models.Model):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    related_name='Reviews',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
festival = models.ForeignKey(
    Festival,
    related_name='Festival_Reviews',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
```

template link:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'festival_list:create_review' festival.pk %}">Add Review</a>
```

Many thanks for your help =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the primary key in the url, for example:

```
path(
    'create/review/<int:pk>',
    views.CreateReview.as_view(),
    name='create_review'
),
```

So the URL that will be derived will look like `create/review/123`, with `123` the primary key of the *festival*.

The url of the review should then look like:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'festival_list:create_review' pk=festival.pk %}">Add Review</a>
```

That being said, it is likely that your `Form` will not accept this, since the festival is *not* filled in, you thus should remove the festival:

```
class CreateReview(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):

    form_class = forms.ReviewFormCreate
    model = models.Review
    template_name = 'festival_list/review_form.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def create_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super(CreateReview, self).create_form(*args, **kwargs)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.festival_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return form
```

and thus remove the `festival` and `user` from the form itself (you probably do not want users to tamper with it, since otherwise people could post a review as if it was another user).

Comment: Hey, I did that. Sorry didn't notice stackOverflow didn't format my urls.py code properly. I updated the post, and unfortunately same error :(

Comment: @OrPreiss: in the `{% url ... %}`, you should write it like `pk=festival.pk`, not just `festival.pk`.

Comment: First, thank you so much for the quick reply!
So I did all that and now I get new error: 
NoReverseMatch at /festivals/55/
Reverse for 'create_review' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 55}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['festivals/create/review/$']

Additionally, I checked and the form is loaded when I remove the entire PK thing.

Comment: @OrPreiss: it really looks as if it did not change the URL. Are you sure you did not construct *two* urls with the same name, since this one has no parameter.

Comment: This is the full Url list
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.FestivalList.as_view(),name='all'),
    path('create/festival/',views.CreateFestival.as_view(),name='create'),
    path('create/artist/',views.CreateArtist.as_view(),name='create_artist'),
    path('<int:pk>/',views.DetailFestival.as_view(),name='single'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/',views.DeleteFestival.as_view(),name='delete'),
    path('update/<int:pk>/',views.UpdateFestival.as_view(),name='update'),
    path('create/review/<int:pk>',views.CreateReview.as_view(),name='create_review'),

Comment: well the strange thing is that it uses `'festivals/create/review/$'`, so without any `pk` parameter. What if you remove the `*.pyc` files, and restart the server?

Comment: Alright, did that and now the error is: NoReverseMatch at /festivals/create/review/55
Reverse for 'create_review' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['festivals/create/review/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Comment: @OrPreiss: that means somewhere there is a `{% url ... %}` without that `pk` (or a `reverse(..)`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your help bro. I'm very new to Django so a still in the shades but will try to explore this.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem because I used this url again in my form page.
Like this:

```
<form
    action="{% url 'readersclub_review_create_urlpattern'}"
    method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit Review</button>
</form>
```

But I did not figure out how to fix it.